# is there any way to insert a list of dictionary into mongodb without for loop using python flask and MongoEngine?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-mongoengine

I need to insert a list of dicts into mongodb. also i need to avoid the duplicate entry from the database. if some data from list is already exists in the db, i need to avoid that data.

Collection name is "TitleTraining"

```
title_list = [{"title":"python"},{"title":"java"},{"title":"react"}]
```

if one title say "python" already exists in collection, i don't need to insert it again.

i inserted it using the following lines of code,

```
for each in title_list:
    each['title'] = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', each['title']).strip()
    if not TitleTraining.objects.filter(**each):
        titleset = TitleTraining(**each)
        titleset.save()
```

Is there any way to insert it without for loop?

Comment: Maybe you need https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [bulk insert](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.insert) to your collection using the `insert` method on your `Document` class, but you need to loop over the list in order to turn it into the proper objects to be inserted.

like the following:

```
TitleTraining.objects.insert([TitleTraining(...), ...])
```

- However, if you want to prevent your code from saving duplicate titles, inside your `TitleTraining` class make sure that `title` field is `unique`.
- for the regular expression cleaning, you can call it inside the class `__init__` method

```
class TitleTraining(Document):
    def __init__(self, *args, **values):
        title = values.get('title', '')
        title = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', title.strip())
        values['title'] = title
        super().__init__(*args, **values)

    ...

    title = StringField(..., unique=True)
```

Now your Document class has what it takes to off-load these unnecessary steps from the loop.

we can do a list comprehension to do the bulk insertion to your collection

```
TitleTraining.objects.insert([TitleTraining(**each) for each in title_list])
```

The only thing left is to handle errors when the `TrainingTitle` is a duplicate during the bulk insert, you can use a query to check for duplicates, it can be a `filter(title__in=[<<<LIST OF ALL TITLES>>>])` to check and exclude them from the insert.